# Cannot inject request paraemter into blade view file

Tags: laravel, request, laravel-blade

I have the following URL:

`https://example.com/?email=test@test.com`

then I have the following blade template

`<input value="{{Request::query('email') or old('email')}}">`

But it's not displaying the email I passed in the get parameter into the input. **Instead, it's displaying the value 1**

Tried searching haven't found a solution that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have `{{Request::query('email') or old('email')}}` which is conditional. It will always return true or false.

Try any of these:

`{{Request::query('email') ||  old('email')}}`

or

`{{Request::query('email') ? Request::query('email') : old('email')}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<input value="{{ request()->email }}">
```